# Python remove tuples and merge the two values from tuples inside them to one item

Tags: python, list, tuples, multi-index

I have list similar to this:

```
[('name', ''),
 ('season', ''),
 ('company', ''),
 ('date', ''),
 ('mean value', 1),
 ('mean value', 2),
 ('mean value', 3),
 ('mean value', 4)]
```

I would like to get rid of the tuples and to merge between the two values if exists, to get the following list:

```
['name',
 'season',
 'company',
 'date',
 'mean value 1',
 'mean value 2',
 'mean value 3',
 'mean value 4']
```

I'm not sure how to do this, looking for ways to do this efficiently.

Comment: `["".join(str(i) for i in tup) for tup in l]`?

Comment: [Freddy Mcloughlan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71855400/12416453) is more pythonic than mine for your use-case IMO.

Comment: @Ch3steR What if the tuple inside the list has more than two elements,@Freddy Mcloughlan is Not dynamic.

Comment: @SharimIqbal I guess OP's data has only two values in each tuple. That's the reason I said Freddy's answer is better. In case the OP has more than 2 values in a tuple `["".join(str(i) for i in tup) for tup in l]` should do it.

Comment: @SharimIqbal *Code needs to be dynamic.* Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add in a space (`mean value 4`):

```
[f"{a} {b}".strip() for a, b in lst]
```

If you don't need a space (`'mean value4'`):

```
[f"{a}{b}" for a, b in lst]
```

---

Note: This answer only works for tuples of length 2

Comment: What if the tuple with more than 2 values. He get this error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: OP's question was about tuples of length 2. This will not work for any length other than 2, but the other answers may.

Answer (score 2):

```
list(map(lambda t: " ".join(map(str, t)), mylist))
```

or

```
[" ".join(map(str, t)) for t in mylist]
```

edit: removed lambda, thanks @Timus

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is easy to understand and works.

```
tup = [('name', ''),('season', ''),('company', ''),('date', ''),('mean value', 1),('mean value', 2),('mean value', 3), ('mean value', 4)]

def func(value):
    string = ''
    for a in value:
        string += str(a)
        string+=' '
    return string.strip()
result = list(map(func,tup))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `if-else` in a list comprehension

```py
stuff = [('name', ''),('season', ''),('company', ''),('date', ''),('mean value', 1),('mean value', 2),('mean value', 3), ('mean value', 4)]

joined = [f'{a} {b}' if b else a for a, b in stuff]
print(joined)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
test_list = [('name', ''),('season', ''),('company', ''),('date', ''),('mean value', 1),('mean value', 2),('mean value', 3), ('mean value', 4)]
new_list = []
for item in test_list:
    new_list.append(' '.join(map(str,item)).strip())
```